# Detecting pinching in desktop browsers

Tags: javascript, dom, desktop

So with scrolling events I can detect panning gestures in desktop browsers and modify content accordingly. But is there a way to detect also pinching (zooming) gestures? So that instead of browser zooming the whole site (or not doing anything) I could modify a DOM element accordingly.

There are laptops with such trackpads (like Magic Trackpad and Force Touch Trackpad). So gestures can be captured, but how can I use them in desktop web apps?

Imagine that you could pinch and zoom in our out in Google Map in desktop browser. And pan left and right with a hand gesture.

Comment: react to the zoom, not the pinch.

Comment: But I do not want the whole page to zoom. I just want to modify a subset of it. (Imagine an embedded Google Map. I want to detect pinching once one is with a mouse over that map.)

Comment: you just react to the zoom command, you can prevent any actual zooming from the event handler, but it will fire when the event should (when pinched and not from KB)

Comment: How you detect the zoom command on desktop browser?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using some specialized library like [hammer.js](http://hammerjs.github.io/). Have a look at [this example](http://codepen.io/jtangel) of the hammer.js documentation, where they utilize pinch gesture recognition.

According to that example detecting the pinch gesture could be as simple as:

```
var myElement = document.getElementById('myElement'),
    mc = new Hammer.Manager(myElement),
    pinch = new Hammer.Pinch();

mc.add(pinch);
mc.on("pinch", function(ev) {
    console.log('You sir did just pinch!');
});
```

However, if you only wanted to react to the changing viewport within your layout, you might be better off with using responsive design features like media queries.

---

Edit: It does not work that way. Thats because the desktop browsers do not yet support gesture events. However the second part of my answer remains true: you can use media queries based on the viewport dimensions and you could hook in on the resize events of the window as usual.

Comment: I do not think pinch gesture works with hammer.js in a desktop browser? At least not in Firefox and Chrome: https://hammerjs.github.io/browser-support/

Comment: I would like to not zoom the whole window. I would want to modify only a subset of document. Imagine an embedded Google Maps. I would like that when pinching over the Google Maps, that would modify, but the whole window should stay.

Comment: Well it won't work with gestures.You might be able to "hack" something if the element in question can steal the focus from the window.. like an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for the same thing - pinching on only a specific DOM element and not entire webpage (let's an embedded drawing app instead of the google maps example).

In the developer console from Chrome and Opera select Toggle Device Toolbar and chose a touch device. Pinching can be simulated by keeping the shift key + left mouse click pressed. Then check out the monitorEvents : https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/command-line/events?hl=en

Additionally, Hammer.js has a touch emulator library:

`<script> TouchEmulator(); </script>
     function log(ev) {
     console.log(ev.touches);
     }
 document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', log, false);`

Later edit. For the Google Maps specific example the viewport is set like this so that it uses its own zooming libraries and not the browser embedded .

```
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1">
```